# How to get current build number in flutter?

Tags: flutter, versioning

The one given by `pubspec.yaml` seems to be just a initial number. `version: 1.0.0+1`

There is an internal counter stored somewhere.

How can I check the internal build number?

Comment: internal? what do you mean by that?

Comment: @pskink I mean a hidden state.

Comment: @HardikK it is the number after the plus sign of `version: 1.0.0+1`

Comment: There is no hidden, internal build number. You increment this value manually whenever you like. From your code you can use [this package](https://pub.dev/packages/package_info_plus) for example to get it.

Comment: @PeterKoltai, but my builds still has auto increased build number. So maybe it is XCode setting?

Comment: I don't use XCode for building, but I guess you can have some automation (build phase script) to increment the build number, but I don't think that it is the default behaviour.

Answer (score 2):

- Android:

  build.gradle, versionCode and versionName
- iOS:

  Info.plist, CFBundleVersion

Or flutter package: https://pub.dev/packages/package_info_plus

Answer (score 2):

```
  package_info_plus: ^1.0.6
```

Example:

```
PackageInfo packageInfo = await PackageInfo.fromPlatform();
String version = packageInfo.version;
```